# Is the pitch of 他にも Heiban?

Tags: particle-に, particle-も, pitch-accent

When the Heiban 他(ほか{LH}) combines with にも to form

> ほか + に + も

the standard pitch rules would indicate that it's pronounced ほかにも{LHHL}; however, OJAD states that the pitch of 他にも is actually ほかにも{LHHH}:

> [image]

Is this just an OJAD error? Can the pitch of 他にも sometimes change depending upon how it's used (e.g. is it ほかにも{LHHH} when spoken as a Negative Polarity Item, but otherwise ほかにも{LHHL})?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OJAD error, it’s ほかに＼も.

Regarding a negative polarity usage: it would turn into heiban *theoretically*, but the problem is that this も basically grammatically *must* be the “also” meaning (as opposed to the “not a single” meaning found in NPI) so there is basically no such usage. Sentences like 他にもないか見てみる are valid but they mean “check if there is(n’t) an extra one” and it’s pronounced ほかに＼も, it’s not a NPI.

Comment: Is there an implicit を after 他にもないか in 「他にもないか見てみる」?

Comment: Yes but it’s more common to omit it, so a bit different than normal particle dropping

Comment: Since を takes a noun as an argument, does that then mean there's also an implicit nominalizing の before it the (also implicit) を? As in: 「他にもないのをか見てみる」?

Comment: Huh? You got it backwards. It’s 「他にもないかを」. か has a nominalizing effect

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot that か can nominalize like that.